# I lost my data from datastore on GAE how Google app engine helps to restore my data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

I am working with project using GWT on GAE. In my application there are customers, contracts and I am saving customer in customer entity and contracts in contract entity. But I lost few customers and few contract from  customer and contract entity from my application on Google App Engine. I want those customers and contracts restore in my application so how Google helps?

Comment: Hey Vijjya ,,, adana hyanga delete madidi

Comment: no way to get it back if you didn't make a backup. Google will not help you because its impossible to recover.

Comment: Zig , thank you for your response i did not backup it . may be there is any possible ways to restore from google app engine??

Comment: no, it's gone after you delete it.

Comment: Sudhir how u know me ??

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can set up a cron job to do backups. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups#Setting_Up_a_Scheduled_Backup